# Locating URL used to dynamically fill content in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When extracting content from web pages served directly, it's easy. You just look at the HTML code and use regular expressions to extract the content ("Alpha" and "Beta" in this case).

```
<ul>
<li>Alpha</li>
<li>Beta</li>
</ul>
```

However, with JavaScript being used more and more to fill content, you run into cases like this:

```
<ul id="dynamic">
</ul>
```

Obviously, there is some JavaScript code somewhere that fills the list, and most times it first fetches a JSON object via some URL, and then uses this to fill the content.

However the amount of JavaScript in pages these days may be enormous, and obfuscated to boot, so how do you quickly find the code that fills the list?

Actually it's not really the code that's important, but the URL that contains the data ("Alpha", "Beta").

How do you efficiently find this URL in any/most given Web pages? Can browser Developer Mode help? Or are you left with painstaking needle-in-the-haystack analysis of the JavaScript code?

Comment: You can check the network tab in the developer tool and filter them out leaving only the ones that were done asynchronously

Comment: OK! I'm onto this now, but the network section of developer mode (in Safari) lists the URL only as its basename ("abc.jsp"). The only way I can find the full URL is by hovering the basename to reveal a tooltip which disappears after a few seconds. There is no way to Ctrl+C it or anything. I'll have to photograph the tooltip with my phone or something! How can I get the full URL into my clipboard?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about safari I usually use Chrome to develop. In chrome you can right-click them and then you have an option to "Open link in a new tab"

Comment: Double-clicking the basename in Safari opens a new tab with the URL. So problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab in the developer tool and filter them out leaving only the ones that were done asynchronously, then double-click the entry in Safari to open a new tab with the URL.